# Meaningfulness of glInvalidateFramebuffer with shared attachments

Tags: opengl-es

I have a scenario where I switch between two FBOs. Both FBOs share the same depth/stencil attachment, only the color attachments are different. Now, if I call glInvalidateFramebuffer on the depth/stencil attachment before calling glBindFramebuffer, will this have any benefit at all since the attachment is reused between the FBOs and the gpu should be able to recognize this and avoid unnecessary memory operations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, yes. Once you have marked an attachment as "invalid" then the contents are undefined until something writes new data into it.

In practice, I suspect you are at the mercy of how good drivers are at state tracking across FBOs if you want to get the full benefits.

I'd recommend issuing all necessary clears and invalidates for every FBO separately; they are not expensive operations.